# componentSeparatedByString not working with NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays, xcode, string

I am trying to split a string into an array. This is the code that i'm using (also, I'm using ARC):

```
test = @"this$is$a$test";  

myarray = [test componentSeparatedByString:@"$"];
```

`test` and `myarray` are synthesized properties.

I'm getting an error:

> receiver type 'nsstring' for instance message does not declare a method with selector 'componentseparatedbystring'

Can anyone help me with this matter? 
thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is `components` not `component`. Make sure you refer to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) when you get warnings stating that a method does not exist.

```
myarray = [test componentsSeparatedByString:@"$"];
```

Comment: also: you should use your autocompletion. After typing the first part of the method name (i.e. "comp...") you would see what methods are available.